# Access a URL (w/ cookies) using sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, cookies, urllib2

I'm trying to write a program that uses sockets to connect to a website and save data from it. The issue I have is that I can't figure out how to connect to something besides index.php. Like, say I want to connect to page1.php instead of index.php. Can anyone help me with that?

Also, is there a way to get all the data at once, rather than in chunks? Or do I just have to loop until I'm done?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `urllib` and friends?

Comment: If you show us what code you've got so far, we'll be able to tell you how to modify it. Otherwise, we'll just tell you to use the standard `urllib` library.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't know there were any higher level libraries. I feel like an idiot. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I'm just wondering real quick though, is it possible to add cookies with urllib in any way? Any other library or module?

Comment: Welcome to Python! People say it comes with "batteries included", which means the standard library has all kinds of good tools to do common things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using the `urllib2` and `cookielib` modules. Here's [an example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/302930-cookielib-example/) from the Python Cookbook ([see more](http://code.activestate.com/search/recipes/#q=cookie+OR+urllib)).